# Where is Java EE 6 SDK for Windows 7 x64?

Tags: java, sun

Sun's website is confusing.
I am looking for Java 1.6 Enterprise Edition SDK for WINDOWS 7 64-bit.

I found the 64-bit Standard Edition, and the 32-bit Enterprise edition.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, how about that:

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=java_ee_sdk-6u1-wjdk-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_SMI

Answer (score 0):

The 32bit vs 64bit refers to the JVM itself, as well as some core libraries. So the 64bit JavaSE download is the JavaSE runtime on top of a 64 bit JVM.

On top of that, the majority of the JavaSE APIs and libraries are not specific to 32bit or 64bit. JavaEE runs on top of JavaSE, and so it's not 32bit-64bit specific.

So, pick the JavaSE appropriate to your environment, and don't worry about it for JavaEE.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think of this link: https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=java_ee_sdk-6u1-wjdk-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_SMI

Answer (score 0):

I had Java SE 64-bit installed and I tried to install Java EE. I had the following error (well something like that):

Missing Java installation...
If Java is installed on your computer you can try : Java_EE.exe -j (Java(TM) Directory Installation)

- I tried the -j command with JDK, JDK\bin, JRE, JRE\bin
- I tried to reinstall java 64-bit
- I tried re-setting JAVA_HOME, PATH and CLASSPATH variable just for
  the sake of it...

Nothing worked

I installed Java SE 32-bit, double click Java_EE.exe and everything work...

EDIT : And now to complement the strangeness when I go through the Java_EE.exe installer, the installer spot my Java SE 64-bit edition (maybe because I set the environments variables)